# Query username with symbol char in PHP

Tags: php, sql

Currently username stored in the database includes any characters and symbols. User can enter any username they want (yes, it was my fault because not set rules for username earlier).

It becomes an issue when I want to display all profile details based on username with any characters and symbols.

For example:

> username: Friends & Co Ent.

I get the username from href which is like this:

```
<td><a href="profile_detail.php?user=<?php echo $rec['username'];?>" class="btn btn-primary">View</a></td>
```

and display profile based on query like this:

```
$user =$_GET['user'];

$user_detail = "SELECT * FROM user_detail WHERE username = '$user'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$user_detail);
$rec = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

//display user name

<div class="form-group">
 <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user_name" name="user_name" value="<?=$rec['user_name']?>" readonly>
</div>
```

The form does not display any detail regarding the user. I have done create the "on the go" solution which is query `WHERE username LIKE '$user%'`

Any other suggestion for the best solution?

Comment: `var_dump($_GET['user']);` and `var_dump` what is in the database and view the source of the page.  One of them undoubtedly has `&amp;`

Comment: In the href you probably need `urlencode($rec['username'])`

Comment: Why would any characters in the username be a problem? You have plenty of mistakes in this code, but the characters in the username are not the problem.

Comment: @AbraCadaver great sir! now i am using ```urlencode``` in my codes

Comment: @Dharman yes, I will upgrade my codes later. maybe I need to learn more PDO

Answer (score 1):

The username containing "weird" characters is not a problem. Usernames can contain any character possible.

However, you have 3 serious problems with your code.

1. **SQL injection.**

   To prevent SQL injection you must make sure that you always parameterize your SQL values. If you are using mysqli (I recommend using PDO instead) then your code would look like this:

   ```
    $stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT * FROM user_detail WHERE username = ?');
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $user);
    $stmt->execute();
    $rec = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_array();
   ```
2. **XSS (Cross site scripting)**

   You must remember that any output in HTML context should go through `htmlentities()`

   ```
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user_name" name="user_name" value="<?= htmlentities($rec['username']) ?>" readonly>
    </div>
   ```
3. **URL query strings must be escaped properly.**

   To create URL query string use `http_build_query()`

   ```
    <?php
    $url_query_string = http_build_query(['user'=>$rec['username']]);
    ?>
    <td><a href="profile_detail.php?<?= htmlentities($url_query_string) ?>" class="btn btn-primary">View</a></td>
   ```